# Centering imagestring() with php?

Tags: php, css

I am trying to create an image for my welcome page and want to center the strings dinamically otherwise its too bad with different usernames like: John and Alexandra.

```
header("Content-type: image/png");

$string1 = "Hello!";
$string2 = "Welcome to our website!";
$srting3 = "$username";

$font1  = 5;
$font2  = 3;
$font3  = 3;

$img_w = 240;
$img_h =  64;

$image = imagecreatetruecolor ($img_w, $img_h);
$white = imagecolorallocate   ($image, 255,255,255);
$black = imagecolorallocate   ($image,   0,  0,  0);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);

imagestring ($image, $font1, 110,  0, $string1, $black);
imagestring ($image, $font2,  60, 20, $string2, $black);
imagestring ($image, $font3, 105, 40, $string3, $black);

imagepng ($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `imagefontwidth()` function to get the width of each character and multiply it with `strlen($string)` you can also use the `imagefontheight()` to update the height.

```
header("Content-type: image/png");

$string1 = "Hello!";
$string2 = "Welcome to our website!";
$srting3 = "$username";

$font1  = 5;
$width1 = imagefontwidth($font1) * strlen($string);
$height1 = imagefontheight($font1);

$font2  = 3;
$width2 = imagefontwidth($font2) * strlen($string2);
$height2 = imagefontheight($font2);

$font3  = 3;
$width3 = imagefontwidth($font3) * strlen($string3);
$height3 = imagefontheight($font3);

$img_w = 240;
$img_h = 64;

$image = imagecreatetruecolor ($img_w,$img_h);
$white = imagecolorallocate ($image,255,255,255);
$black = imagecolorallocate ($image,0,0,0);
imagefill($image,0,0,$white);

imagestring ($image,$font1,($img_w/2)-($width1/2),        0,$string1,$black);
imagestring ($image,$font2,($img_w/2)-($width2/2), $height1,$string2,$black);
imagestring ($image,$font3,($img_w/2)-($width3/2), $height1+$height2,$string3,$black);


imagepng ($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with this:

```
<?php 
$im = imagecreate(150,50);
$text = 'bobcat';
$bgd = imagecolorallocate($im, 180,180,180);
$mid = imagecolorallocate($im, 160,160,160);

$fw = imagefontwidth(5);     // width of a character
$l = strlen($text);          // number of characters
$tw = $l * $fw;              // text width
$iw = imagesx($im);          // image width

$xpos = ($iw - $tw)/2;
$ypos = 20;

imagestring ($im, 5, $xpos, $ypos, $text, $mid);           // text in the middle

header("content-type: image/png");
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Or think about:

1. Create a background image
2. Create a transparent image with text
3. Trim transparent image with text and get its dimensions
4. Do simple math txt_img.x = (bkg_img.width-txt_img.width)/2;